# Cant use input on pig Latin translator

Tags: python, input

So I'm making a pig Latin translator to challenge my self on what I've learned in python so far and I'm pretty much done with it but whenever I try to translate a word with a console input, the whole this goes to shit and doesn't work. Can someone explain to me why that happening?

The code is below and along with the error.

```
input("What would you like to convert?")
#Whole function
def converter (input):
    #variables and their deffnition
    w = str(input)
    word = w.upper()
    x = ((word)[0])
    z = "ay"
    p = "yay"
 # words that start with a vowel
    if x == ("A" or 'E' or 'I' or 'O' or 'U'):
        pyg_word = (word[0] + (word[1:len(word)]).lower() + p)
        return pyg_word

#most words that start with a constant

    elif x == "B" or 'C' or 'D' or 'F' or 'G' or 'H' or 'J' or 'K' or 'L' or 'M' or "N" or 'P' or 'Q' or 'R' or 'S' or 'T' or 'V' or 'W' or 'X' or 'Z':
        pyg_word1 = (word[1] + word[2:len(word)].lower() + word[0].lower()+ z)
        return pyg_word1
    
#Words that start with a Y

    elif x == "Y":
        pyg_word2 = (word[1:len(word)] + word[0].lower() + z)
        return pyg_word2

    elif ((word[0] and word[1] and word[2]) == ("B" or 'C' or 'D' or 'F' or 'G' or 'H' or 'J' or 'K' or 'L' or 'M' or "N" or 'P' or 'Q' or 'R' or 'S' or 'T' or 'V' or 'W' or 'X' or 'Z')):
        pyg_word3 = (word[2:len(word)] + word[0:1] + z)
        return pyg_word3
#othershit
    else:
        fail = "can't convert word yet. please wait"
        return fail   
print (converter(input))
```

Result:

```
What would you like to convert?Dogs
Built-in function input><ay
```

Comment: In which variable do you stored the input?

Comment: The immediate problem is that you are calling `converter(input)` on the last line, where indeed `input` is the built-in function.

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain why the input is the built-in-function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a minor correction here - you have to grab the input from the terminal and assign it to a variable to be able to use the raw string value. So, if you do this, your translator should work

```
my_input = input("What would you like to convert?")
print (converter(my_input))
```